# Converting integer to list of digit strings in Python

Tags: list, python-2.7, integer

Is there anyway to convert a series of integers into a list 
e.g.
`12345`
to `['1','2','3','4','5']`

Comment: I mean probably not into *that* list, but yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of these: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1906717/478656; http://stackoverflow.com/q/780390/478656; http://stackoverflow.com/q/13905936/478656; http://stackoverflow.com/q/974952/478656; http://stackoverflow.com/q/5242798/478656;

Answer (score 1):

```
list(str(i))
```

The reason this works is that `str` turns the integer (e.g. 12345) into its string representation (`'12345'`), and strings are iterable, thus direct conversion to a list (of component characters) is possible.

```
In [1]: i = 12345

In [2]: list(str(i))
Out[2]: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by "series of integers"

If you mean a big numbers, Lola's solution is find, but the easier one is:

```
n = 12345
a = [c for c in str(n)]
```

If you mean "turn array of integers in array of strings"

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = list(map(int, a))
```

Comment: `[c for c in str(n)]` <-- if you're not doing anything to each member there's no reason to use a comprehension. Directly cast to list: `list(str(n))`.